# Figuring Out How To Take Screenshots with TestNG on Test Failure

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

Okay, I've looked on this topic for quite a bit and have tried multiple solutions to my problem, but I seem to keep getting into roadblocks. I'm trying to setup a general TakeScreenshot after it hits the max of retry attempts with my RetryAnalyzer class. However, I keep getting hit with ClasscastExceptions when adding the Driver and I'm having trouble how to get that same driver initialized in the Base Test, (besides setting to static). Here are my classes I have setup for Screenshot Capture:

Driver Class:

```
public class Driver implements WebDriver {

protected WebDriver driver;
String browserName;
public static JavascriptExecutor js;


    public Driver (String browserName) {
    this.browserName = browserName;
    if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./resources/webdrivers/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
        js = (JavascriptExecutor) this.driver;
    }
    // Other methods for different browsers
```

BaseTest (Start Portion):

```
@Listeners({TestMethodListener.class, ScreenshotListstener.class})
public class BaseTest {
protected Driver driver;
DummyTestAccount dummyAccount = new DummyTestAccount();
String browserName = getParamater("browser");


 @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
 public void setUp() {

  driver = new Driver(browserName);
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  }

  private String getParamater(String name) {
  String value = System.getProperty(name);
  if(value == null) {
      throw new RuntimeException(name + "missing parameter");
  }
  return value;
  }

  //Further setup for my extended test classes
```

RetryAnalyzer:

```
   public class RetryAnalyzer extends BaseTest implements IRetryAnalyzer {
   int count = 0;
   private static int maxTry = 1;
   ScreenshotListstener picCapture = new ScreenshotListstener();

   public boolean retry(ITestResult arg0) {
    if(count < maxTry) {
        count++;
        return true; //Retry for flaky tests with unexpected variables 
    } else {

        picCapture.onTestFailure(driver, arg0);
        return false; //Don't retry the failed test Capture Screenshot.
    }
   }
```

Screenshot Class:

```
  public class ScreenshotListstener extends TestListenerAdapter {


    public void onTestFailure(Driver driver, ITestResult result) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String methodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
    SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss");

        File bugPic = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        try {
            Files.copy(bugPic, new File("./target/surefire-reports/error-pics/"+ methodName + "_" +formater.format(calendar.getTime()) + ".png"));
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Currently with this setup, I'm getting hit with a NullPointerException occurring in ScreenshotListener class when initializing on the bugPic File instance. Is there something that I'm missing? Would this current setup be following towards a good practice for test frameworks?

Any advice is helpful.

Thanks.

(Update):

Figured out my issue thanks to Grasshopper's advice.

Driver Class:

```
public class Driver implements WebDriver {

protected WebDriver driver;
String browserName;
public static JavascriptExecutor js;
public TakesScreenshot bugCapture;

    public Driver (String browserName) {
    this.browserName = browserName;
    if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./resources/webdrivers/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
        js = (JavascriptExecutor) this.driver;
        bugCapture = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
    }
    // Other methods for different browsers
```

BaseTest (Start Portion):

```
@Listeners({TestMethodListener.class, ScreenshotListstener.class})
public class BaseTest {
protected Driver driver;
public static final ThreadLocal<Driver> driverThread = new ThreadLocal<Driver>();
DummyTestAccount dummyAccount = new DummyTestAccount();
String browserName = getParamater("browser");


 @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
 public void setUp() {

  driver = new Driver(browserName);
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driverThread.set(driver);
  }

  private String getParamater(String name) {
  String value = System.getProperty(name);
  if(value == null) {
      throw new RuntimeException(name + "missing parameter");
  }
  return value;
  }

  //Further setup for my extended test classes
```

RetryAnalyzer:

```
   public class RetryAnalyzer extends BaseTest implements IRetryAnalyzer {
   int count = 0;
   private static int maxTry = 1;
   ScreenshotListstener picCapture = new ScreenshotListstener();

   public boolean retry(ITestResult arg0) {
    if(count < maxTry) {
        count++;
        return true; //Retry for flaky tests with unexpected variables 
    } else {

        picCapture.onTestFailure(driverThread.get(), arg0);
        return false; //Don't retry the failed test Capture Screenshot.
    }
   }
```

Screenshot Class:

```
  public class ScreenshotListstener extends TestListenerAdapter {


    public void onTestFailure(Driver driver, ITestResult result) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String methodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
    SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss");

        File bugPic = driver.bugCapture.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        try {
            Files.copy(bugPic, new File("./target/surefire-reports/error-pics/"+ methodName + "_" +formater.format(calendar.getTime()) + ".png"));
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TestNg will only inject the "ITestResult result" parameter to the onTestFailure method. Either make the driver static or use ThreadLocal to store the driver instance for a thread...

Comment: @Grasshopper, I attempted to resolve the situation through a ThreadLocal or the driver is static by declaring either of these in variables in BaseTest class then call on them in the onTestFailure method. After several tries and adjustments, I get the same ClassCastException or error in my git bash stating there was an error in the forked process followed by a ClassCastException statement.

Comment: The class Driver that you have created does not implement the TakesScreenshot interface. You will need to use the protected 'driver' field inside this Driver class.

Comment: That did it. Once added a TakesScreenshot instance at the bottom of my Driver constructor, I'm getting screenshots and the method name created with the dates when the issue occurred. I thought there was a way to call that instance after construction and add to it, but this may be the best way to set this up at the start rather than calling on it when needed. Thank you.